# PostgreSql database seek After formatting PC

Tags: windows, windows-7, postgresql-9.2

I've been working lately on a personnel project using PostgreSQL 9.2 as a DataBase source, I made my hard disk as an external HD in on other PC, I am wondering if I can get my old data base and import it in the new PostgreSQL installed in the new PC? both PostgreSQL (in the new PC & in the external HD) have the same version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time searching for a way to solve this, I am afraid there is nothing to do if you had a PostgreSQL database on 32bit System and want it to run in PostgreSQL server on 64bit System. Hopefully for me I could generate my database simply by using Hibernate options. And now I got another reason to love using Hibernate :D